# Hanging a garden hose holder and need information on framing under a window

Tags: timber-framing

How far apart are the studs underneath a large picture window?  I am testing for studs about 1 1/2 ft up from the base.

Comment: Where are you? Why type of home is it?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming 1) You're in the U.S., and 2) you're in a conventionally-built home, 16" on center. The layout should follow through from the rest of the wall.

You might invest in a basic stud finder. They're pretty good these days.